# Charging my 18 V mowing robot

Tags: voltage, batteries, solar-charge-controller

I have a mowing robot, Bosch Indego 500 S. It says it has an 18 V lithium battery.

I would like to charge it with a battery. I can only find 12 V or 24 V batteries in the stores. Is the 12 V still OK? Is the 24 V too much? Or should I buy a charger controller?

I can't connect the robot directly to my electric house power, so I was thinking about a battery and a solar panel. (I see they sell controllers with those, maybe that will be enough?) Should I also buy an inverter in this case?

Comment: I suggest you to forget about this and use an extension cord for the dedicated charger. Making a charger for lithium batteries is not a beginner project.

Comment: Of course you can get an inverter powered by battery and outputting 120VAC (or 220VAC) and use it to charge your robot. But it sounds...suboptimal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I totally agree it wouldnt be the optimal choice. Can you tell me, should the battery in this schema 12v or 24v,or it doesnt really matter?

Comment: If you're a beginner, you should buy a package that includes solar panel, battery, and inverter, that's guaranteed to work.  Don't mess around -- do some research to find out who's reputable, and just buy from them.

Comment: Ok of course  would buy a pack that already contains everything. But shoud the battery in this lack 12v or 24v, to charge a 18v li battery? Or it doesnt matter?

Comment: It depends on the inverter / other stuff being connected to it. If you buy a package, it will come with a suitable battery

Comment: To expand on what Eugene said about it not being a beginner project, you should be aware that improperly charging a lithium battery can cause a serious fire and result in bodily injury and damage to your property. The danger of hacky charging approaches with LiPo really can't be understated. Proper chargers have a BMS that includes layered safety protections.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Ill investigate package that suits my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the install video: https://www.bosch-diy.com/gb/en/p/indego-s-500-06008b0202-v52870

It seems that the docking station is powered by a low voltage DC supply, find out what that voltage is (it may be different from the battery voltage) then go to the computer store and buy a car laptop charger for that voltage, that will convert 12V into what the docking station wants.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, I didn't consider the docking station and its supplier. I'll look into what parameters are written on it!

Answer (score -2):

12V wont be enough for a 18V motor.The motor will rotate very slowly or not rotate at all.24V is too high , you will damage it.But you can use the 24V battery by feeding into a voltage regulator of 18V then connect the your motor to the output of the voltage regulator.

But be careful the power wasted on the voltage regulator will be 6I so this will work only for small currents.

Comment: He;s trying to charg the existing internal battery - not replace it. [I didn't downvote your answer].